# AKS no longer able to connect to Azure Files PVC with Output: mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system mount error(19): No such device

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-files

This deployment has been running fine for months. It looks like the Pods redeployed early this morning, I think probably related to applying `2023.10.31 (AKSSecurityPatchedVHD`.

The Pods that mount Azure Files for file storage are stuck in `ContainerCreating` with the following error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    3m46s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned env/<deployment> to <aks-node>
  Warning  FailedMount  3m45s (x2 over 3m46s)  kubelet            MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "<pvc>" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = volume(<resource-group>) mount //<stuff>.file.core.windows.net/<pvc> on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/file.csi.azure.com/<stuff>/globalmount failed with mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o mfsymlinks,actimeo=30,nosharesock,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,<masked> //<stuff>.file.core.windows.net/<pvc> /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/file.csi.azure.com/<stuff>/globalmount
Output: mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

Please refer to http://aka.ms/filemounterror for possible causes and solutions for mount errors.
  Warning  FailedMount  104s  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[file-storage], unattached volumes=[file-storage kube-api-access-xbprr]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Kind of stumped. What I've tried:

- Redeploying the pod deployments
- Redeploying storage
- Confirmed the pvc being referred to does in fact exist

Issue persists and I'm not sure what to try next other than redeploying everything.

There isn't anything helpful at http://aka.ms/filemounterror. Nothing has changed in the environment for months. Another environment is running fine and it is basically a duplicate of this one, so seems isolated to this one. These are Linux nodes.

---

My `storage.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: file-storage
  namespace: env
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-storage
  namespace: env
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: default
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
```

`postgres-storage` seems to be fine, it is the `file-storage` that is being an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This didn't affect us for AKS but it did for other VMs in our Azure Tenant; it seems that [there is an issue with the CIFS module](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-azure/+bug/2042092) not being included in the MS Kernel builds

> Between 6.2.0-1015 and 6.2.0-1016, the CIFS module was moved from fs/cifs/* to fs/smb/client/*, fs/smb/common/* and fs/smb/server/*. The inclusion list (root/debian.azure-6.2/control.d/azure.inclusion-list) was not updated for this change, so the module is not included in the linux-modules-6.2.0-1026-azure package.

I'm not sure why it hasn't affected Kubernetes version 1.27.3; perhaps MS haven't moved that to the 6.2.0.1206 kernel yet?

A work around has been posted:

```
## Install older kernel
sudo apt install linux-image-6.2.0-1015-azure

## Remove newer kernel (select NO when asked)
sudo apt remove linux-image-6.2.0-1016-azure

## Reboot
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Both environments were running on `kubectl=1.26.6`. Upgraded the one that was having issues to `1.27.3` and that fixed it. Why one environment was having issues and not the other I'm not sure.